# Easy desktop unlock

Tags: bluetooth, lock-screen

I am writing because I would like to use some simple way to unlock my PC desktop. A few years ago I used BlueProximity, but it is deprecated, and the Python fork has also been 2 years out of maintenance.
Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what answers might meet the criteria of a "*simple way*," as that term currently seems undefined. A method that is simple for Person A might be unworkable for Person B.

Comment: Of course , simpler than typing a password

Comment: If inserting (and removing) a specific USB drive is *"simple"* enough for you [look at this guy's site](https://blog.mcdope.org/2020/10/03/pam_usb-linux-authentication-with-usb-media/). They have a PPA which you can add to your repository lists, and then install the app as usual. The configuration information is in the github page. **Note:** I have never used it. This information is from a Google search.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it and see how it works